# What strategies are effective against a spot destruction deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Standard (Return to Ravnica, M14, and the first Theros set), a friend of mine is currently working with a tri-color RGB deck heavy on control via spot destruction: [Abrupt Decay](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abrupt%20Decay), [Dreadbore](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dreadbore), [Ultimate Price](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ultimate%20Price), and other cards that follow the format of *"Destroy target X"*.

Between those cards, said friend can fairly effectively keep our side of the board clear and pave the way for a powerful mid- to late-game creature (e.g. [Polukranos, World Eater](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polukranos%2C%20World%20Eater), which doubles as another destroyer) to end the game.

What strategies are generally effective against destruction-focused control decks like this? (Bonus points for strategies currently viable in Standard)

Comment: Sounds like a midrange deck with a lot of removal. See [What's actually good against Jund?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/11202/1910)

Comment: @AlexP That sounds like a fit - it is a Jund deck with a focus on removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's best against spot removal?

The absolute best decks against decks packed with spot removal is decks without any (good) targets for them. This will make those cards dead or bad draws. So how do you do that?

- **Play a deck without creatures**. Maybe you can build a combo-, planeswalker- or mill-deck without creatures?
- **Creatures with hexproof, shroud or other protection**. Their spells can't hit them, so they're useless.
- **Low values targets**. Tokens and creatures with CITP effects comes to mind. It's not fun playing [Dreadbore](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dreadbore) on a [Lingering Souls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lingering%20Souls) token or on a [Venser, Shaper Savant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Venser%2C%20Shaper%20Savant).

--

In your specific case: Is anyone playing control decks? The deck you describe tend to have a quite rough time against those.